# Transforming the inputs using python scripts to feed into the tensorflow lite ML Kit for firebase connected to android app

Tags: java, python, android, machine-learning, tensorflow-lite

I have trained a keras model(converted to .tflite for ML kit) which doesn't take raw data coming from android sensors as input but instead it takes some preprocessed data. The preprocessing of data is too complicated to be done in Java, but is feasible enough to do using a python script. So I was wondering if there is a way for me to preprocess the raw data input using python and then feed it into my .tflite model.

Answer (score 1):

In terms for android app, Python might not integrate well locally. However, you can try following ways based on the resources you have.

- **Cloud computation** - Use REST API call to get pre-processed data from Python script hosted on Google Cloud, store it if required and run the model predictions on the android or on cloud based on your requirements.
- **Chaquopy Plugin** - Try plugin for Android Studio’s Gradle-based build system called [chaquopy](https://chaquo.com/chaquopy/) which enables basic intermix of Java and Python in android.
- **C++ JNI integration** - Try to perform data preprocessing in C++ and integrate using Java Native Interface (JNI).